# Probably Another Javascript Closure Issue

Tags: javascript

I think I'm having a closure issue, but I'm having a hard time trying to solve it.
I thought that using $.map would prevent any problem.

See the javascript below (require Zepto or jQuery to work) or access the working code https://jsfiddle.net/rowcp07n/4/:

```
"use strict";
var log = function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
  for(var i in arguments){
    output.append(JSON.stringify(arguments[i]));
    output.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));   
    output.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));   
  }
};

function EmptyAction(){
    self = this;
    self.play = function(){
        self.complete();
    };
};

function Scene(row, i){
    log('Constructing Scene '+i);
    var self = this;
    self.index = i;
    self.steps = $.map(row, function(col, i){
        return new SceneStep(row[i], self, i);
    });
}

function SceneStep(col, scene, i){
    log('Constructing SceneStep '+i+' for Scene '+scene.index);
    var self = this;
    self.index = i;
    self.action = new EmptyAction();
    self.action.parentStep = self; 
    self.action.complete = function(){
        log('Complete handler for SceneStep '+ self.index);
    };
    self.value = col;
}

var data = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
];

function ViewModel(data){
    var self = this;
    self.scenes = $.map(data, function(row, i){
        return new Scene(row, i);
    });
}

var vm = new ViewModel(data);
log('Triggering complete of 0-0');
vm.scenes[0].steps[0].action.complete();
log('calling play() of 0-0');
vm.scenes[0].steps[0].action.play();
```

I expect to see, at the end of the log, **"Complete handler for SceneStep 0"**
but I'm getting **"Complete handler for SceneStep 2"**

Can anyone point to me what I'm missing?

Comment: Missing `var` from `self = this;` in `EmptyAction()` (which makes `self` global.)

Comment: @JJJ `self` [may already be global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/self) depending on the environment ;) It actually overwrites it.

Comment: Yuo are both right! Thank you guys!

Comment: PS: You can also [picoQuery](http://picoquery.com) as an alternative to jQuery and Zepto. (But not Cash for this code, because Cash 1.3.0 has a bug in the map method...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JJJ pointed, I forgot to declare the var self in class EmptyAction.